# Parse Cloud Code Save All

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, save, parse-cloud-code

So I have a list of about 200 rows in my Parse Core. I am trying to create a job that runs through the entire list and changes the entire column of `push` to `0`. I am trying to do so with this code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("SetPush", function(request, response) {
                   //take in JSON with dict

                   var newts = new Array();

                   for ( var i = 0; i < request.params.push.length; i++ )
                   {
                   //add these entries to db
                   var DataClass = Parse.Object.extend("AllTeams");
                   var dataupdate = new DataClass();

                   var origdata = request.params.datalist[i];
                   dataupdate.set("push", "0");

                   newts[i]=dataupdate; //add another item to list

                   }

                   Parse.Object.saveAll(newts,{
                                        success: function(list) {
                                        // All the objects were saved.
                                        response.success("ok " );  //saveAll is now finished and we can properly exit with confidence :-)
                                        },
                                        error: function(error) {
                                        // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
                                        response.error("failure on saving list ");
                                        },
                                        });

                   //default body does not do  response.success or response.error 

                   });
```

As you can see my class is `SetPush` and I want to update the `push` column all the way down. The problem I believe lies in this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < request.params.push.length; i++ )
```

When I run this code in the Cloud Code, it returns this error:

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at main.js:43:60'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Dear Nicholas; I have question. Is push kind of list that is given to request? (you call push from request params)?

Comment: @kingspeech I honestly have no idea what push is supposed to be. That is what is wrong haha!

Comment: Dear Nicholas;From your post, I can gather information such that; post must be a kind of list whose property length must be valid. Just check the place that you trigger the cloud function, so you can see the parameters that you give to request. Hope this helps.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

.length is undefined because request.params.push is an object.  Looks like you want to iterate through a list you're passing in to this cloud function using the input parameter request.params.push, if/assuming the caller is passing in a valid JSON as 'push' then you can do something like this

```
Parse.Cloud.job("SetPush", function(request, response) {                    
//take in JSON with dict         
var parsedJson = JSON.parse( request.params.push );                         
var newts = new Array();                     
for ( var i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++ )                    
{                    
//add these entries to db                    
var DataClass = Parse.Object.extend("AllTeams");                    
var dataupdate = new DataClass();                     
var origdata = request.params.datalist[i];                    
dataupdate.set("push", "0");                     
newts[i]=dataupdate; //add another item to list                     
}                     

Parse.Object.saveAll(newts,{                                         
success: function(list) {                                         
// All the objects were saved.                                         
response.success("ok " );  
//saveAll is now finished and we can properly exit with confidence :-)                                         
},                                         
error: function(error) {                                         
// An error occurred while saving one of the objects.                                         
response.error("failure on saving list ");                                         
},                                         
});                     //default body does not do  response.success or response.error                      
});
```